# Cloudwatch Logs Insights search filter in mutliple messages

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

this is how my log looks

```
2024-03-16T23:21:21.275Z ff84d7a6-991a-**** unauthorized_error
2024-03-16T23:21:21.275Z ff84d7a6-991a-**** client: client1
```

I want to search for: `unauthorized_error` but if client is not `client1`
as you can see the other filter is in another message so doing this doesn't work

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log 
| filter @message like /(?i)unauthorized/ and @message not like /(?i)client1/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 10000
```